# UITableView pushes new UITableView

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I have a UTTableView that displays a list of items from an SQLite database. That works great.
I want the user to click on one of the items in the ListView and that pushes a new TableView that shows data on another ListView from the SQLite database.
eg: user selects Apple from the list on TableView_1
I want the new TableView list to display the types of apples. How do I tell the second TableView to populate the list with the types of apples.
any ideas would be great I cant get past this part in my project.
David

Comment: Why don't you populate the second table in the same way, you did the first?

Answer (score 0):

You can load the data into the same table again, as Matthisas indicates.

Or you can segue to another UITable (in another View Controller maybe) in which you load the data. It is easy to identify the selected line in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

So you can do something like:

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  selectedFruit=[selectionTableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetailsSegue" sender:self];

}